# Cabinet Properties aren't showing up! Archimesh Broken?

Tags: modeling, mesh, archimesh-add-on

i'm following a tutorial on how to design interiors and in the start he (Blender Guru) edits a cabinet (height size, countertop length, bevels etc.). As soon as he presses cabinet, a window with these properties pops up. When I do it, nothing happens. I am stuck with this problem now for over 2 weeks. I'd appreciate any help with this. Thank you
[image: Blender Guru'S Tool Bar]
[image: My Tool Bar: Nothing]

Comment: Maybe he has a different version of the addon. I recently noticed that it changed a bit too

Answer (score 0):

You have to click on the left bottom side tab that pops up when you add a cabinet. Click on that popup tab called *Cabinets* and you will get your properties.